# Ajax onchange combobox not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i know this question has been asked in many another case in this site. But still, i dont have the right answer to solve my problem .

i want to make the ajax function for my combo box and textarea. So when i select an option in the combo box, text inside textarea will change depending on the combo box's selected value.

---

UPDATED: my textarea code

**this is my  combobox and textare code :**

```
<select class="form-control" name="option_template" id="template" onchange="get_template(this.value);">
  <option value="" selected="" disabled=""> -- Pilih Template --</option> 
<?php foreach ($template as $template){
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $template['id'];?>"><?php echo $template['nama'];?></option>
<?php                            }
?>
</select> 
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
     <textarea id="template-content"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

**this is my javascript function and the ajax**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      // alert("hai");
      function get_template(id){
       alert(id);
        $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          url:'<?php echo base_url();?>broadcast/ajax_template',
          data:{option:id},
          succes:function(msg){
            alert(msg);
             $('#template-content').val(msg);
          }

        });

      }


    </script>
```

---

**and the last , this is my php function that retrieve the post from ajax**

```
public function ajax_template(){
    $id=$this->input->post('option');
    $q=$this->M_template->get_template($id)->row_array();
    echo "Test output".$q['content'];
}
```

---

when i run the code above, the **alert(id);** in the javascript **get_template()** function syntax is working, so i get the option value everytime i select the option. But the problem is i cannot get the output data from the ajax's post. Can someone please help me with this? i know this is maybe a basic knowledge but i've spent hours to solve this problem , thank you :)

Comment: You mean ajax is calling php function but not returning value, right?

Comment: Could you please show me you error which is occurred?

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan yap, its not returning any value

Comment: @Kamlesh theres no error, even my console is clear.

Comment: Just use print_r($q);  and check what is output

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan i already did that in the php function, but its not returning anything in the javascript function. I already add string "Test Output" in the php callback so i suppose that that string will be returned in the ajax success function.

Comment: You mean nothing in the console output, Can I see this online?

Comment: Try below:- 
$response =array();
$response['status'] = true;
$response['data'] = $data;
// set header json
$response = json_encode($response);
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output($response);

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan  im running this on the localhost, probably i will move this to the server first if the problem still not solved so you can check it online, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird and i dont know why my previous code is not working. But i found a new way to do this by using **change()** function to the select syntax and use the get method instead of post.

this is my javascript and ajax function

```
  $("#template").change(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("template");
        var id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({ 
          url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Broadcast/ajax_template?option='+id, 
          success: function(msg){
             $('#template-content').val(msg);
      }});
    });
```

i removed **onchange** attribute of my select syntax
and change the php function to get the id from **post** to **get**

```
$id=$this->input->get('option');
```

Comment: default method is get

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax_template() method

You are getting response from M_template as an array. you cannot echo array as like that.
Use echo json_encode($arrayname). in your case echo json_encode($q['content']);

and make sure that in ajax you mention dataType:'json'

Answer (score -1):

Could you please call your function

```
public function ajax_template(){
    $id = $this->input->post('option');
    $q=$this->M_template->get_template($id)->row_array();
    echo "Test output".$q['content'];
    exit;
}
```

Without using ajax and check it will display anything or not. Please pass static value on `$id` variable.

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the query, i use static variable on id and it echoes the right value from the db.